# Visual Studio 2013 support for Parasoft C++Test 9.6

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, parasoft

I'm a newbie for using Parasoft. We are planning to use Parasoft C++Test 9.6 version for Code Coverage. But, I'm not sure how to import a Visual Studio 2013 project into this. In the Advanced Settings I selected 'Visual Studio 12.0 Tool chain'. But, auto detect couldn't find the compiler and linker. So, I manually gave the path to the 'cl.exe' & 'link.exe' in the installation folder of VS2013. But, still it gives the error 'Cl is not in the PATH' while building.

Please let me know what I'm missing. At the basic, is it possible to import VS2013 project into this version of Parasoft?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gomu,

I suppose that you are using Parasoft C++test Eclipse edition (standalone), and it might be easier for you to get from Parasoft Parasoft C++test Visual Studio plugin.
Then you don't have to import Visual Studio project, but you will have whole functionality of C++test in Visual Studio.